# How to send a UDP packet to the HLDS Server in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, udp, indy

I'm trying to send the A2A_PING UDP packet to the HLDS server as described [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries) using Delphi XE4. However, I'm not getting any response. When I tested using [Packet Sender](https://packetsender.com/), I get the expected response just fine in Packet Sender.

What I'm trying to do is create a server monitor to send ping's on it's UDP port. So, my app would always run locally on the server using its local IP. The server's UDP port is 27015.

The UDP packet I'm trying to send is:

> Hex: FF FF FF FF 69
>
> String equivalent: ÿÿÿÿi

Here is what I've tried to far:

```
unit uFrmMain;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ShellAPI, IdUDPServer, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdUDPBase, IdUDPClient, IdSocketHandle, IdGlobal;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    btnSendMessage: TButton;
    btnInitialize: TButton;
    procedure btnSendMessageClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
    procedure btnInitializeClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    function String2Hex(const Buffer: Ansistring): string;
    procedure Initialize;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

const
  Host = '172.30.0.96';
  TargetPort = 27015;
  LocalListenPort = 47001;
  MessageToSend = 'ÿÿÿÿi';  // need to send: FF FF FF FF 69

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;
  udpServer: TIdUDPServer;
  udpClient: TIdUDPClient;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMain.Initialize;
var
  binding: TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  // Setup UDP Server
  udpServer := TIdUDPServer.Create(frmMain);
  udpServer.Active := false;
  binding := udpServer.Bindings.Add;
  Binding.IP := Host;                 // local host ip
  binding.Port := LocalListenPort;    // Listen for incoming messages on 47001
  udpServer.OnUDPRead := IdUDPServer1UDPRead;
  udpServer.Active := true;

  // Setup UDP client
  udpClient := TIdUDPClient.Create(frmMain);
  udpClient.Host := Host;       // Local host ip
  udpClient.Port := TargetPort; // Send messages to 27015
  udpClient.Active := true;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnInitializeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Initialize;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnSendMessageClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    udpClient.SendBuffer(Host, TargetPort, ToBytes(MessageToSend));
end;

procedure TfrmMain.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
begin
    ListBox1.Items.Add(BytesToString(AData));
end;

function TfrmMain.String2Hex(const Buffer: Ansistring): string;
begin
  SetLength(result, 2*Length(Buffer));
  BinToHex(@Buffer[1], PWideChar(@result[1]), Length(Buffer));
end;

end.
```

**UPDATE** based on Remy's suggestions, I have tried this, too:

```
unit uFrmMain;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ShellAPI, IdUDPServer, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdUDPBase, IdUDPClient, IdSocketHandle, IdGlobal;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    btnSendMessage: TButton;
    btnInitialize: TButton;
    procedure btnSendMessageClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
    procedure btnInitializeClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    function String2Hex(const Buffer: Ansistring): string;
    procedure Initialize;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

const
//  Host = '172.30.0.96';
  Host = '192.168.190.1';
  TargetPort = 27015;
  LocalListenPort = 47001;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;
  udpServer: TIdUDPServer;
//  udpClient: TIdUDPClient;
  binding: TIdSocketHandle;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMain.Initialize;
var
  bytes_received: integer;
begin
  // Setup UDP Server
  udpServer := TIdUDPServer.Create(frmMain);
  udpServer.Active := false;
  udpServer.DefaultPort := 0;
  binding := udpServer.Bindings.Add;
  Binding.IP := Host;                 // local host ip
  binding.Port := LocalListenPort;    // Listen for incoming messages on 47001
  udpServer.OnUDPRead := IdUDPServer1UDPRead;
  udpServer.Active := true;

  // Setup UDP client
//  udpClient := TIdUDPClient.Create(frmMain);
//  udpClient.Host := Host;       // Local host ip
//  udpClient.Port := TargetPort; // Send messages to 27015
//  udpClient.BoundIP := Host;
//  udpClient.BoundPort := LocalListenPort;
//  udpClient.ReceiveTimeout := 2000;
//  udpClient.Active := true;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnInitializeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Initialize;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnSendMessageClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MessageToSend: TIdBytes;
begin
  SetLength(MessageToSend, 5);
  MessageToSend[0] := $FF;
  MessageToSend[1] := $FF;
  MessageToSend[2] := $FF;
  MessageToSend[3] := $FF;
  MessageToSend[4] := $69;
//  udpClient.SendBuffer(Host, TargetPort, RawToBytes(MessageToSend, SizeOf(MessageToSend)));
  binding.SendTo(Host, TargetPort, RawToBytes(MessageToSend, SizeOf(MessageToSend)));
end;

procedure TfrmMain.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
begin
    ListBox1.Items.Add(ToHex(AData));
end;

end.
```

I must be missing something very obvious since Packet Sender works just fine.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: In Unicode Delphi, MessageToSend is a Unicode string. ToBytes(MessageToSend) will use the default UnicodeString encoding to create a byte sequence. Use the debugger to see what acually is sent.

Comment: I actually don't want to send the string but rather the actual bytes: FF FF FF FF 69 instead of the string. Going to see if I can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be using strings for your messages (especially Unicode strings if you are using Delphi 2009+). The protocol you are using is binary in nature, not textual.  You need to operate with raw bytes, eg:

```
const
  MessageToSend: array[0..4] of Byte = ($FF, $FF, $FF, $FF, $69);

procedure TfrmMain.btnSendMessageClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  udpClient.SendBuffer(Host, TargetPort, RawToBytes(MessageToSend, SizeOf(MessageToSend));
end;

{
Alternatively:

procedure TfrmMain.btnSendMessageClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MessageToSend: TIdBytes;
begin
  SetLength(MessageToSend, 5);
  MessageToSend[0] := $FF;
  MessageToSend[1] := $FF;
  MessageToSend[2] := $FF;
  MessageToSend[3] := $FF;
  MessageToSend[4] := $69;
  udpClient.SendBuffer(Host, TargetPort, MessageToSend);
end;
}

procedure TfrmMain.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Add(ToHex(AData));
end;
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your alternative method. When I run it locally, I'm not seeing any response from the server in the IdUDPServer1UDPRead event. Is there anything I could check? Packet Sender is able to send the bytes and get a response.

Comment: Typically, a UDP server would send a response back to the same IP/port that sent the request. So why are you expecting your `TIdUDPServer` to receive anything at all? It is not listening on the port that `TIdUDPClient` is sending from. So either use `TIdUDPClient` to read the response, or use `TIdUDPServer.Binding` to send the request. You don't need to use both `TIdUDPClient` and `TIdUDPServer` together, unless you really need to operate on two different ports.

Comment: How does a TIdUDPClient listen to a server response? I don't see any events other than the Status event. How would you do that if I wanted to send it via the TIdUDPClient and get the response?

Comment: The `OnUDPRead` event is useful when you don't know ahead of time when data will arrive, or you want to write your code asynchronously so you are not blocking the code while waiting for data. But in this case, since you are sending a request and expecting an immediate response, you could use any of the available `TIdUDPClient` reading methods. For instance, you could call `ReceiveBuffer()` immediately after calling `SendBuffer()`. Just be sure to set a non-infinite `ReceiveTimeout` so you don't block your code forever if a response does not arrive.

Comment: Otherwise, as I suggested earlier, you could just get rid of the `TIdUDPClient` altogether and use the `TIdUDPServer` for sending requests AND receiving responses. UDP is connectionless, so you don't HAVE to use `TIdUDPClient` in a client environment. `TIdUDPServer` can also be used as a client.

Comment: Thanks Remy. I made the changes based on your suggestion to use the UDPServer's binding. See code above. When I use binding.SendTo, I'm not receiving any data back in the server's IdUDPServer1UDPRead event though. Am I missing something else?

Comment: Is the target server running on the local machine, or remote over the network? Your code suggests the former, since you are having `TIdUDPServer` listen on the same IP that it sends to. But, if the target server is running remotely, make sure to bind `TIdUDPServer` to the local IP of a network adapter that is connected to a network that can reach the target server, and then send messages to the target's IP instead of the local IP. What are the actual parameters that you are putting into Packet Sender when it works correctly?

Comment: Both IP's are local IP's. Host = '172.30.0.96' is the remote server's local IP address running on a Windows Server 2012 R2. Host = '192.168.190.1' is my local IP. I'm running the same server on my local dev machine. What I'm trying to do is create a server monitor to send ping's on it's UDP port. So, my app would always run locally on the server using its local IP. The server's UDP port is 27015.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What parameters are you putting into Packet Sender when it works, and are you putting those same parameters into `TIdUDPServer` when it doesn't work? You would need to bind `TIdUDPServer` to the local machine's IP (`192.168.190.1`), then send messages to the target server's IP (`172.30.0.96`). Is that what you are doing in Packet Sender? If you follow this, you wouldn't need to run your app on the same machine as the target server, provided there is no firewall blocking messages.

Comment: In Packet Sender, I type in the hex values to send "FF FF FF FF 69". I specify the Host (my local IP) with 192.168.190.1, set the port at 27015 and select UDP protocol. Then I just send it. I get the expected response as FF FF FF FF 6A 00. In my app, I select the local port 192.168.190.1 as the host. See above. Both are running locally, server, my app, Packet Sender. None of this communication needs to go out on the Internet.

Comment: Then Packet Sender is likely letting the OS bind the socket implicitly.  You can do the same in `TIdUDPServer` by setting the `Binding` to `0.0.0.0:0`. But even if you bind `TIdUDPServer` locally to `192.168.0.1:47001` and then send messages to `192.168.0.1:27015`, you should be getting a response back. It is too bad you *aren't* running the apps on different machines, then you could use packet sniffers like Wireshark to diagnose problems with routing messages. When both are running on the same machine, packet sniffers don't usually work, but at least you can use `netstat` instead